# .net web services to wcf

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

i make some internal changes to a project and i need to transfer a web service to a wcf.
The wcf "will be exposed" as web service again. What i want to achieve, is to transfer a method from a web service which contains a xsd file to the wcf.

In this project the former developer has used if i am not mistaken a schema-fitst approach.

i don know how to convert this functionality to wcf. The problem is that the method the ws has, it use a string parameter which then is parsed to the xml which gives the assosicated class-object in order to use it in the code.
But i suppose the client is aware the structure of this xml. How will expose this from wcf? is it enough to add as parameter to my wcf method the class i expect?

Comment: Can you show a minimal code example of what your starting point is and maybe the skeleton of the .svc file you are trying to create?

Comment: I dont have the code with me now, but i read somewhere that i could svctool.exe along with the current.wsdl & current.xsd to create the classes needed and then to use them in my new wcf. The purpose of this task i have, is to change the current web service to wcf which will be exposed as wsdl again because we need the other client programs to have access to this method  by only chaning the url

Comment: Okay, so you read an article like this... http://www.bloggedbychris.com/2012/08/08/net-4-5-contract-development-create-service-contracts-wsdl/

Comment: It was usefull the link. Thank you.
Eventually i understood what was going on with the WS i had. The ws's method had as parameter a string and the expected string was an stringXml which should obay to an xml parse to object from a gien xsd.
So i will recreate this simple method to my wcf and i will give them again the xsd as the internal body of my ws's function will remain the same